# How can I use SP parameters as table and column names within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
create procedure <procedure>
(
    @tbl as varchar(50)='product',
    @col as varchar(50)='proid'
)
as 
begin
    select @col from @tbl 
end
```

Comment: Because it was not designed that way.

Comment: **You can** if you generate a dynamic statement within. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_table

Comment: @oded , can u explain the how it is designed?

Comment: SQL was designed many years ago. The design doesn't allow for usage of parameters for table and column names.

Comment: as i given default value , at compile time doesn't the select statement get converted to valid one?

Comment: i know i may sound stupid but

Answer (score 2):

Because you can't use parameterized table or column names by default. Yhe only way you can do it is by creating dynamic SQL in a string and then executing that string. eg,

```
create procedure <procedure>
(
    @tbl as varchar(50)='product',
    @col as varchar(50)='proid'
)
as 
begin

   Declare @SQL VarChar(1000)

   SET @SQL = 'select ' + @col + ' from ' + @tbl 
   Exec ( @SQL)
end
```

- [Execute Dynamic SQL commands in SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Which of course, only opens you to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @Oded, definitely, i agree.